# How to get some records in the DolphinDB table like mysql's limit

Tags: mysql, sql, dolphindb

Suppose I have the following table with a total of 20 rows.

```
t=table(1..20 as id, 1..20 as val);
```

Now I want to get the rows from 10 to 15. How do I write a SQL statement? Can query like limit in mysql?

Comment: You're trying to achieve this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

I think DolphinDB just added the limit clause. Now you can write

```
select * from t limit 10,15
```